# What does NBF stand for in JWT context?

Tags: jwt

According to [the docs of Identity Server](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html), there's always the following four claims provided in each token:

- Issuer name - *iss*
- Client ID - *client_id*
- Lifetime - *exp*
- Scope - *nbf*

Given the lifetime is computed as expiration occasion, I understand all of the codes except for the last one. What does the code "*NBF*" stand for?

I even checked the [disambiguation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NBF) but there's nothing relating tokens at all.

Bonus question. What's the reason behind the codes being of different format? I can't help wondering why *client_id* isn't following the same pattern and set to *cid*. I sense some historical context...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### *Not before*

That's what `nbf` means.

The usage of this claim is optional and it identifies the time *before* which the token *must not be accepted*.

See the definition from the [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519):

> [**4.1.5.  "nbf" (Not Before) Claim**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.5)
>
> The `nbf` (not before) claim identifies the time before which the
> JWT MUST NOT be accepted for processing.  The processing of the
> `nbf` claim requires that the current date/time MUST be after or
> equal to the not-before date/time listed in the `nbf` claim.
> Implementers MAY provide for some small leeway, usually no more
> than a few minutes, to account for clock skew. Its value MUST be a
> number containing a NumericDate value.  Use of this claim is
> OPTIONAL.

The lifespan of the token starts after the time stated in the `nbf` claim and ends at the time stated in the `exp` claim.

---

**Addressing your *bonus question*:**

It's important to highlight that `nbf` is a [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1) claim [registered in IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/jwt/jwt.xhtml) while `client_id` is not. But it doesn't prevent `client_id` to be used.

Claim names can be defined at will by those using JWTs. The claims defined in the [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519), however, are intentionally short:

> All the names are short because a core goal of JWTs is for the representation to be compact.

This document also states the following:

> Because a core goal of this specification is for the resulting representations to be compact, it is RECOMMENDED that the name be short -- that is, not to exceed 8 characters without a compelling reason to do so.

Comment: Oh, that's such a case of +1... I see how I misinterpreted the referred words from the text in the parenthesis: *...contain claims about the **scope**, **lifetime** (nbf and exp), ...*. Stupid donkey... As for *scope* and *client_id*, it seems that the implementors of Identity Server went against the naming convention of JWT, right?

Comment: @KonradViltersten I've added more details to my answer to address these concerns :)